# Modify specific XML from python?

Tags: python, xml, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to modify an XML attribute every time my program starts.

Basically, I'm creating a GUI with PyGObject, and I want the version number in the about box to automatically update.

The XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.6 -->
  <object class="GtkAboutDialog" id="aboutDialog">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="border_width">5</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">About NetGUI</property>
    <property name="modal">True</property>
    <property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
    <property name="program_name">NetGUI</property>
    <property name="version">0.5</property>
    <property name="copyright" translatable="yes">Copyright (c) 2013. Cody Dostal   </property>
    <property name="comments" translatable="yes">NetGUI is a GUI frontend to NetCTL, a network manager developed for Arch Linux.</property>
    <property name="website">https://github.com/codywd/NetGUI</property>
    <property name="website_label" translatable="yes">GitHub</property>
...
```

How could I automatically edit the Version line to read a variable and change to it?

I have a progVer (program version) variable that it would use. Therefore, I would only increment progVer and it would automatically increment the XML file. If possible, I would like to avoid adding dependencies.

My problem is as follows: 
My program has a variable that states the program version (progVer is the variable, 0.3 at the moment). I have an external XML file (UI.glade) that holds my about box code. The XML has a property name for version, which I have to manually change to keep about box version with the program version. I want the XML file to automatically update to the newest version, as stated by progVer. I'm not sure how exactly to go about this.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Updated to state problem.

Comment: My question was more going in the direction of: What did you try? How far did you get? Did you read about Python xml-tools? Did you check other questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python? Do you want to parse your file manually, ... Did you read http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses Python properties to auto-save the XML.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class ProgramProperties(object):

    def __init__(self, xmlfile):

        # Parse the XML file
        self.__xmlfile = xmlfile
        self.__xml_tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
        self.__version_element = self.__xml_tree.getroot().find(".//property[@name='version']")

        # Get an in-memory copy of 'version'
        self.__version = float(self.__version_element.text)

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self.__version

    @version.setter
    def version(self, vers):

        # Avoid unecessary file I/O
        if self.__version != vers:

            # Store in-memory
            self.__version = vers

            # Save the version to the file
            self.__version_element.text = str(vers)
            self.__xml_tree.write(self.__xmlfile)


prog = ProgramProperties('testdata.txt')

# Update the version, which automatically saves it in the setter
prog.version = 3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.builder = gtk.Builder()
    with open('ui.glade', 'r') as f:
        self.glade = f.read()
    self.glade = self.glade.replace('[VERSION_TOKEN]', self.version, 1)
    self.builder.add_from_string(self.glade)
```

1. Read the Glade file.
2. Replace a token you defined within.
3. Build GUI using function `add_from_string`.